# Sensible way to extend requests.Response Class?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to extend `requests.Response` but I'm not sure how to go about it.

What I want is to extend `requests.Response`. The problem I see is that I'd have to create an entirely new fork of the library, or in the very least create a custom adapter and implement custom code for this.

I'm currently storing the response in an attribute of my new class, but this would mean my custom `APIResponse` does not actually behave like an extended `requests.Response` object.

This is my current dummy work around.

```
class APIResponse:
    def __init__(self, req_response, formatted_json=None):
        self._content = req_response._content
        self._response = req_response

    @property
    def response(self):
        return self._response
```

As stated above, I'd like my custom class to behave like a `requests.Response` object, with some extra features. Since the `Response` objects are generated at a very low level, namely the `HTTPAdapter` module in the `requests` library, I'd have to write a custom adapter as well - and, logically, also customize the `requests.Sessions` class, where it's called.

Which all leads me to belive I'm missing something here.

Is there a sensible way to extend `request.Response` objects, without substantial amounts of code?

I have also tried 'wrapping' a class around an instantiated `Response` object, but it looks very hacky:

```
class APIResponse(Response):
    __attrs__ = ['_content', 'status_code', 'headers', 'url', 'history',
                 'encoding', 'reason', 'cookies', 'elapsed', 'request',
                 '_formatted']

    def __init__(self, req_response):
        self._content = req_response._content
        self._content_consumed = req_response._content_consumed
        self.status_code = req_response.status_code
        self.headers = req_response.headers
        self.url = req_response.url
        self.history = req_response.history
        self.encoding = req_response.encoding
        self.reason = req_response.reason
        self.cookies = req_response.cookies
        self.elapsed = req_response.elapsed
        self.request = req_response.request
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What comes first to mind when seeing your "hacky" it has the advantage to work.

However, there is a risk that you could forget some attributes that are needed for the method you want to use: why not simply iterate over the __dict__ attribute to create your wrapper ?

Here it how it looks:

```
class APIResponse(Response):
    def __init__(self, req_response):
        for k, v in req_response.__dict__.items():
            self.__dict__[k] = v
```

It makes the code more compact, but I have to admit that it is still very hacky.

Comment: cleaner and more elegant. Also does what I need without hassle. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I'm aware I'm late to the party here, but I've been looking at the same thing myself and thought I would share my solution.

The requests.Response class doesn't get instantiated in the usual way, an empty instance is created, and then a setter method is used to apply the state.

```py
import requests


class MyResponseSubClass(requests.Response):

    def __init__(self, response: requests.Response):
        self.__setstate__(response.__getstate__())
        pass


r = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data={'key': 'value'})

my_response = MyResponseSubClass(r)

print(my_response.url, my_response.status_code, my_response.reason)
```

I create a subclass that extends the requests subclass, and then I am able to pass a response object to that class.  It gets the state of that response object, and then applies that state to a newly instantiated child class of the response subclass.

Comment: Interesting API there, I wonder why it has such state handling methods? Anyway, the problem here (other than that it's hacky) is performance - you end up cloning everything from the original `Response` into a new custom instance, it's quite wasteful. Might or might not be a problem, of course. Other problem is that streaming responses are eagerly consumed (again, maybe a problem, maybe not).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind to affect other codes depending `requests` (in same interpreter), you can monkey patch the `Response` class:

```py
def patched_func(self, rvalue):
    return rvalue

requests.Response.patched_func = patched_func

resp = requests.get("https://httpbin.org/get")

resp.patched_func("Another value")
# => "Another value"
```